# Google compute engine Error: API rate limit exceeded

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

I've been getting this message on Google compute engine "Error: API rate limit exceeded" (billing enable etc), for about 1 day now, I can't even enter to modify quotas by control panel. Does anyone know what other option does one have to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This may be due to the relevant API not enabled and/or billing is not turned on for your project.

---

Go to your [Google Developers Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) and enable **Google Compute Engine**

[image: Google Developer Console]

If prompted, enable billing.

Answer (score 2):

There's a daily quota and a minutely quota. If you've continued to see these errors for more than 24 hours, then you have a script that's burning through your api quota. You'll need to find that script and shut it down. Alternately, you can visit your Google accounts page and revoke the access token associated with the offending process.